# How can I override rows from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, subquery

I have two tables:

**TableA**

```
ID  Name
--  ----
1   aaa
2   bbb
3   ccc
4   ddd
```

**TableB**

```
ID  Name
--  --------
3   WWXXYYZZ
```

I want to select from both tables, but skip the rows which exist in TableB. The result should look like this:

```
ID  Name
--  --------
1   aaa
2   bbb
3   WWXXYYZZ
4   ddd
```

I have tried `union` and `join` but did not figure out how to achieve this.

```
-- Did not work
select *
from TableA
union
select *
from TableB

-- Did not work
select *
from
(
    select *
    from TableA
) x
join
(
    select *
    from TableB
) y
on x.ID = y.ID
```

Comment: @DaleK I have tried union and inner/left join.

Comment: What if B has a row with value `5`... will that show up in the result?

Comment: @TheImpaler No, their IDs must match. TableB is always a subset of TableA.

Comment: @DaleK Updated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could left join `b` on to `a`, and use `coalesce` to prefer `b`'s rows:

```sql
SELECT    a.id, COALESCE(b.name, a.name) AS name
FROM      a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select a.id, coalesce(b.name, a.name)
from a left join b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: you likely meant to left join since b is a subset of a and OP seems to want all rows in a.

Answer (score 0):

One method is `union all`:

```
select b.*
from b
union all
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 from a where a.id = b.id);
```

You can also choose from `a` and override with values from b:

```
select a.id, coalesce(b.name, a.name) as name
from a left join
     b
     on a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: It's a complicated huge query, I cannot just use it again.

Comment: @Farhan why not? Use a CTE or temp table to reuse the results.

Comment: @Farhan . . . You realize that the answer you accepted is the second query here.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, but he posted it first. You want me to accept your answer?

Comment: @Farhan . . . Actually, if you look at the timestamps, this one was posted first.  In any case, as the OP you can accept whatever answer you think is best.

Answer (score 0):

A more complex method uses `ROW_NUMBER` which might be necessary if your query is significantly more complex than shown. It also handled the case where a row exists in TableB but not TableA (which is not clear from your question).

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (id INT, [Name] VARCHAR(12));
DECLARE @TableB TABLE (id INT, [Name] VARCHAR(12));

INSERT INTO @TableA (id, [Name])
VALUES
(1, 'aaa'),
(2, 'bbb'),
(3, 'ccc'),
(4, 'ddd');

INSERT INTO @TableB (id, [Name])
VALUES
(3, 'WWXXYYZZ'),
(5, 'TTTGGG');

SELECT id, [Name]
FROM (
    SELECT id, [Name]
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [Priority] DESC) Rn
    FROM (
        SELECT id, [Name], 0 [Priority]
        FROM @TableA
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, [Name], 1 [Priority]
        FROM @TableB
    ) X
  ) Y
WHERE Rn = 1;
```

Returns:

```
1   aaa
2   bbb
3   WWXXYYZZ
4   ddd
5   TTTGGG
```